# Authorization to google drive api using Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-api-client, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to make a simple application (like a Service account -in google api console) which send a file to an google drive.

I have got code like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'launchy'

#extra
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth'

client = Google::APIClient.new({:application_name => "testdevelop",:application_version => "1.0"})
drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')

####################################################################################
# Initialize OAuth 2.0 client    
# client.authorization.client_id = '111062272758.apps.googleusercontent.com'
# client.authorization.client_secret = 's8j3VQwCvlyz2Hcpr06xrVfr'
# client.authorization.redirect_uri = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
# client.authorization.scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
# uri = client.authorization.authorization_uri
# Launchy.open(uri)
# $stdout.write  "Enter authorization code: "
# client.authorization.code = gets.chomp
# client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

####################################################################################
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('12355eaee706eb725ff5dd890b5c2bc39d536a53-privatekey.p12', 'notasecret')
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction',
  :issuer => '312062272758-bg7s7ts9f3m11hjetboodre6hfg4qp8q@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  :signing_key => key)
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
#####################################################################################


# Make an API call
# Insert a file
file = drive.files.insert.request_schema.new({
  'title' => 'My document',
  'description' => 'A test document',
  'mimeType' => 'text/plain'
})

media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new('document.txt', 'text/plain')
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => drive.files.insert,
  :body_object => file,
  :media => media,
  :parameters => {
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'alt' => 'json'})

# Pretty print the API result
jj result.data.to_hash
```

When I run it i got an error

> `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Faraday::Error::TimeoutError)

When I uncomment commented code and comment code between line of ############## It is possible to send a file into gDrive but I must enter the authorization code from web browser.

I want to do it automaticly thats i decided to use gDrive like a Service account

I have tried to increase connection time out by adding lines:

```
conn = Faraday.default_connection
conn.options[:timeout] = 500
```

and ofcourse with connection: conn after parametrs in request but i have got another error

> `sysread_nonblock': end of file reached
>   (Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed)

Answer (score 0):

the (ssl)-certificate is missing.
how to fix: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: the answer is and was: "certificate missing" - everything else is a bonus, in order to "have" 30 characters.